# how can i search data in php using explode by sql query?

Tags: php

My database has row with a column like

```
data1+data2+data3+data4
```

How can i search specific value by sql query in php?

For example `data2`?

The `+`s separate each data point.

Comment: Let's rewind, what is the question?

Comment: Show your query which you tried.

Comment: in sql database field value =  "data1+data2+data3+data4"

Comment: i want to search data from this value by mysql query in php

Comment: I can't work out what you are asking, are you asking for information on how you can split a string returned from a MySQL query using the preg_split function?

Comment: It might be easier just to include some code so we can try and work out what you are asking.

Comment: <form method="get" action="">
                          <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
                          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button" />
                        </form>

Comment: Right so you have a query, do you run it or are you wanting to split the `$_GET['searchtext']` string?

Comment: `$_GET['searchtext']` and `<input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>` don't match so you will always end up with an empty string.

Comment: Are you using `+`s in your DB as delimiters and you now want to be able to search by the individual values?

Comment: yes i want to search ndividual values

Comment: You need to normalize your db. It should be one row per value.

Comment: @RamnikRangpariya please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've reformatted your question I think to be clearer, if not please revert it.

Comment: in sql table, fieldname = "data1+data2+data3+data4" .i want to be able to search by the individual values using sql  query

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lcSearchVal = "data1+data2+data3+data4";
$lcSearchVal = explode( '+', $lcSearchVal );

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (';

$data_array = array();
foreach( $lcSearchVal as $lcSearchWord )
{ 
    $data_array[] = 'fieldname LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"'; 
}

$sql .= implode(' OR ', $data_array).')';

print $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like below:

```
SELECT   (data1+data2+data3+data4) AS total 
FROM     Table
WHERE    total LIKE '%YOUR_QUERY%'
```

Now you can use the index **`total`**